# (OCR using cnn) ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 31) are incompatible

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, ocr

I using the dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/landlord/handwriting-recognition to develop an OCR system, I used CNN to develop the model

```
def make_cnn_model():
    inp = L.Input(shape=(256, 64, 1), dtype=np.float32, name='input_data')
    x = L.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inp)
    x = L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = L.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    x = L.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
    x = L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = L.Dropout(0.3)(x)
    new_shape = ((256 // 4), (64 // 4) * 128)
    x = L.Reshape(new_shape)(x)
    x = L.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    x = L.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = L.Flatten()(x)  # Flatten the output for a fully connected layer
    x = L.Dense(len(characters) + 1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='Dense_output')(x)
    model = M.Model(inp, x)
    
    # Compile the CNN model with an optimizer (e.g., SGD) and loss function (e.g., categorical cross-entropy)
    sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
        learning_rate=0.002,
        momentum=0.9,
        nesterov=True,
        clipnorm=5
    )

    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

It always show

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 31) are incompatible
```

here is my model.summary()

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_data (InputLayer)     [(None, 256, 64, 1)]      0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 64, 64)       640       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2  (None, 128, 32, 64)       0         
 D)                                                              
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 128, 32, 64)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 32, 128)      73856     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPoolin  (None, 64, 16, 128)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 64, 16, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 64, 2048)          0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64, 64)            131136    
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 64, 64)            0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 4096)              0         
                                                                 
 Dense_output (Dense)        (None, 31)                127007    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 332639 (1.27 MB)
Trainable params: 332639 (1.27 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

this is my train model code

```
# Add early stopping
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                   patience=5,
                                   restore_best_weights=True)

# Train the model
if 'prediction_model_ocr.h5' not in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\litor\\Desktop'):
    history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=650,validation_data=validation_generator,
                        epochs=10)
```

How should I proceed, or what should I be changing?

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback.